# Insert Value in FieldA from matching ID in FieldB

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have two similar situations.

1) I have a table with ID|Name|ParentID. I'd like to add a field ParentNaame and then have a query step through the table and find the record with the ParentID and store it in the ParentName field.

```
1 | Manhattan | 2
2 | New York | 3
3 | United States |
```

becomes

```
1 | Manhattan | 2 | New York
2 | New York | 3 | United States
```

etc

2) Same thing except the ID/Parent Name comes from a second table

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what a `join` is?  If you have tried any SQL, please add it to the question.

Comment: Only in passing, learning mysql as needed as I go along, added Join to the tags though thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to perform an update-join:

```
UPDATE my_table a 
JOIN   my_table b ON a.parent_id = b.id
SET    a.parent_name = b.name
```

The same principal also holds if you want to take the value of `parent_name` from a different table - just use it in the `join` instead.

Comment: After running it appears as if I run into situations where if two or more records have the same ParentID neither one updates. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If I am not mistaken as well; when running on the same table, if the record with ParentID has a higher ID then the ParentID ID record it does not update. Is there no way to run it 'backwards' too?

Comment: I have for example these two records